# Crediting OpenStreetMap maps in QGIS

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap

OpenStreetMap
[Copyright and License](https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright/en) dictates that the users will give [OpenStreetMap](https://www.openstreetmap.org/search?query=Croatia#map=7/44.407/16.329) credit.

Is there a way to add the credit into QGIS maps automatically?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [OSM](https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=8/31.438/35.074) maps have a semi-automatic way to add credit into the maps.
It need to be activated and once it head it placed at the right-bottom corner of the map.
The first step is to go Properties of the map.

[image: OSM Layer properties]

Then you need to click on the "Place the credit..." box

[image: Place the credit box]

Once you have done this the credit will appear and will be to scale

[image: resulting canvas with credits]