# Adding the details of the map maker into qgis map

Tags: qgis, labeling

I am making maps as part of my academic work.
It is important to have the details of the map maker on these kind of maps, and I am guessing it is also true for maps that are made for clients.

I was wondering is there an easy way to add my details, so they will we be in the corner of the map and up to scale?

Something like the way to [credit OSM maps in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/250491/crediting-osm-maps-in-qgis).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was searching for a solution to this problem and find a nice answer.

In order add your details, or any other caption you like, you need to go to the 
**Toolbar>View -> Decorations -> Copyright label.**

[image]

Once you clicked the "Copyright label" bar a window will open and you will be able to write done your caption , choosing their position and color.

When you are working within this bar you can click "Apply" in order to see the changing you made without closing this window.

The first location choice is a crude one, between the four corners of the map.
[image]

To make the fine tuning used the "Mergin form edge" function: adding numbers into the Horizontal Vertical slots will change the caption location, respectively.
[image]

It's also passable to choose the caption color, but not font style or size.
[image]

Once it's done the caption will be automatically adjusted to the map scale and stat in a fix position.

1:1,000,000 scale.
[image]

1:2,039 scale.
[image]

1:510 scale.
[image]