# Add basemap copyright in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, legend, imagery, basemap, license

I am using the QuickMapServices plugin for basemap imagery and was wondering if I can add a QGIS legend that includes default copyright information? I know this can be done in ArcMap...!

Comment: In a QGIS Print Layout or on an interactive map?

Comment: in print layout!

Comment: Check out [this similar question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/311909/dynamic-copyright-or-layer-credit-in-qgis-3-4) about applying a copyright credit on the map canvas. You should be able to apply the solutions in the print layout by putting one of the expressions in a label.

Comment: Note that not every basemap from the quickmapservices plugin comes with correct, up-to-date copyright information. You can check it in the layer properties.