# Adding OpenStreetMap copyright label

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, labeling

I have looked up [Crediting OpenStreetMap maps in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/250491).

For QGIS 3.22 LTR this seems to be missing or moved somewhere else.

How do I add the copyight label for OSM data ?

I know `View -> Decorations -> Copyright label.`  but in the Q&A above, there is a semiautomatic way of adding it.

Comment: Do you find some usable answer from https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/345953/crediting-qgis-and-source-of-map-data-in-print?